# How to Move Emails Containing Name of a Folder?

Tags: vba, outlook

We manually create a folder each time we get a new client.

I'd like if an email contains a keyword that matches the name of a folder, then move the email to said folder.

E.g.
If email in inbox contains keyword "Apple" and an "Apple" folder exists, then move email to the "Apple" folder. Else nothing.
Similarly, if email in inbox contains keyword "Google" and a "Google" folder exists, then move the email to the "Google" folder. Else nothing.

Without having to set rules for each new folder that is created.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. In VBA you can scan all folders for email with a specific keyword and if a corresponding folder exists in Outlook you could move it to that folder. Let's consider what needs to be done for that. First, you need to scan all folders. The [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the Application class allows to perform a search based on a specified DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) search string. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Read more about that in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

So, you could run a search for items in the background and then at some point when the search is completed you may be notified.

To find the target folder you could iterate over all folders in Outlook recursively. See [Enumerate folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-enumerate-folders) for more information on that.

Finally, to move items you can use the [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.move) method which moves a Microsoft Outlook item to a new folder.